# Plot transition graph in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, plotly, markov-chains

I have data structured in the following way:

```
transition_list <- list(c('A', 'B'), c('A', 'C', 'D'))
```

and I want to plot the transition matrix of the list. We can think of every vector of the list as an individual, and every element of the vectors as the successive states of the individuals.

The plot should be in the following way: I want the edges to have the probabilities of going from a state to another, estimated through the whole list. That is, in here the probability of going from A to B should be 1/2 and the probability of going from A to C should be 1/2. I cannot concatenate the vectors, since this would provide a probability 1 of going from B to A, which is not what it it.

I am aware that [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34370566/r-how-do-i-produce-a-state-transition-matrix-from-a-vector-that-represent-state) is similar, but I would need it with a list of vectors instead of with a vector.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't create the plot for you, but I can create the data that you will need for the plot. My approach is iterative, and to avoid writing for-loops I'm using the `map` function from the `purrr` package.

First, I took the liberty of expanding your data somewhat:

```
transition_list <- list(c('A', 'B', 'D', 'X'), c('A', 'C', 'D', 'X'), c('A', 'B', 'E', 'X'))
```

Next, these are the packages we are going to need:

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
```

First, I'm writing a custom function that will transform one vector into a data frame. Each 'step' results in two values: `from` and `to`. Therefore the length of my loop is equal to the length of the vector minus one.

```
browse_individual <- function(states) {
  map_df(
    1:(length(states)-1),
    ~list(from = states[.x], to = states[.x+1])
  )
}
```

This code is very concise, but here is what it does: the first argument of `map_df` is what we are going to loop over. That's the length of the vector minus one. The second argument is what we want to return for every step, which is a list of two elements, containing the current element as `from` and the next element as `to`. The specific function `map_df` converts the output (a list of lists) to a data frame.

Next, we need to apply this function to every vector in your list.

```
state_changes <- map_df(transition_list, browse_individual)
```

Here I'm using `map_df` again. The output of every step of the loop is a data frame (namely, the one that `browse_individual` returns). All these dataframes are combined into one data frame called `state_changes`.

The following part is some `dplyr` code that counts how often a change occurs and calculates how likely it is, given the `from` position.

```
state_change_prob <- state_changes %>%
  count(from, to) %>%
  group_by(from) %>%
  mutate(prob = n / sum(n)) %>%
  select(from, to, prob) %>%
  ungroup()
```

In the end, we get this result:

```
> state_change_prob
#> # A tibble: 7 x 3
#>   from  to     prob
#>   <chr> <chr> <dbl>
#> 1 A     B     0.667
#> 2 A     C     0.333
#> 3 B     D     0.5  
#> 4 B     E     0.5  
#> 5 C     D     1    
#> 6 D     X     1    
#> 7 E     X     1
```

I hope this is an answer to your question and that you can build the plot based on this data format.